# Print all pages from a TableView

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am trying to print **tablview** in **wpf** but only problem i am getting it prints only first page (like took a screenshot). not all data when scroll down.

```
private void Print(Visual v)
{
    System.Windows.FrameworkElement e = v as System.Windows.FrameworkElement;
    if (e == null)
        return;

    PrintDialog pd = new PrintDialog();
    if (pd.ShowDialog() == true)
    {
        Transform originalScale = e.LayoutTransform;
        System.Printing.PrintCapabilities capabilities = pd.PrintQueue.GetPrintCapabilities(pd.PrintTicket);
        double scale = Math.Min(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth / e.ActualWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight /e.ActualHeight);
        e.LayoutTransform = new ScaleTransform(scale, scale);
        System.Windows.Size sz = new System.Windows.Size(capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.ExtentHeight);
        e.Measure(sz);
        e.Arrange(new System.Windows.Rect(new System.Windows.Point(capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginWidth, capabilities.PageImageableArea.OriginHeight), sz));
        pd.PrintTicket.PageOrientation = System.Printing.PageOrientation.Landscape;
        pd.PrintVisual(v, "print chart");
        e.LayoutTransform = originalScale;
    }
}
```